# How to prevent to all fields from editable with one click with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this HTML code, with which if I click on edit all the fields will become editable,  but I just want the specific row only to be editable not the entire table.

HTML COde:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employeeDetail in employeeDetails | filter:filterUser">
  <td>
    <!-- editable username (text with validation) -->
    <a ui-sref="Reports"><span editable-text="employeeDetail.empName" e-form="tableform" ng-click="seeDetails(employeeDetail.userId)">
                                    {{ employeeDetail.empName || 'empty' }}
                                  </span></a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span editable-text="employeeDetail.departmentName" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)">
                                    {{ employeeDetail.departmentName || 'empty' }}
                                  </span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span editable-text="employeeDetail.empEmail" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)">
                                    {{ employeeDetail.empEmail || 'empty' }}
                                  </span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span editable-text="employeeDetail.empContact" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)">
                                    {{ employeeDetail.empContact || 'empty' }}
                                  </span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span editable-text="employeeDetail.empContact" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)">
                                    NIL
                                  </span>
  </td>
  <td>No Entry Found!</td>
  <td style="padding:5px!important;">
    <i class="fa fa-trash" ng-click="deleteEmp(employeeDetail.userId)">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                     <!-- buttons -->
                                    <div class="btn-edit">
                                      <i ng-show="!tableform.$visible" ng-click="tableform.$show(employeeDetail.userId)" class="fa fa-pencil-square add-icon" title="Edit Employee" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <!-- <button editable-text="employeeDetail.empName">Edit</button> -->
    </div>
    <div class="btn-form" ng-show="tableform.$visible">
      <button type="submit" ng-click="updateEmployee(employeeDetail.empName)" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" ng-click="tableform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
    </div>
  </td>
  <!-- <td><button type="button" ng-show="tableform.$visible" ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Del</button></td> -->
</tr>
```

Comment: Too ambiguous! Create a working snippet, plunker or a fiddle.

Comment: Consider accepting my answer or writing your own if you solved it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own example because yours is too confusing the follow, but the point remains the same.

Essentially,
attach a condition to the employees, or find another way to keep track of them being editable or not. After you do that, you can just attach an `ng-show` to the button and check to see if `employee.editable == true`. If it does, then the `ng-show` will evaluate to true and the button will display.

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("EmployeeManagement", []);

    var EmployeeListCtrl = function () {
        var vm = this;
        vm.employees = [
            { 
              name: "Joe",
              code: "C",
              gender: "M",
              editable: false
            },
            {
              name: "Candy",
              code: "C",
              gender: "Female",
              editable: false
            }
        ];
                
        vm.showDelete = function(employee) {
            employee.editable = (employee.editable === true) ? false : true;
        };
        
    }
    app.controller("EmployeeListCtrl", [EmployeeListCtrl]);
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" ng-app="EmployeeManagement">
        <table class="table" ng-controller="EmployeeListCtrl as vm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product</td>
                    <td>Code</td>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in vm.employees">
                    <td ng-click="vm.showDelete(employee)" style="color:blue">{{ employee.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.code }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.gender }}</td>
                    <td width="15%">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="employee.editable">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```